# how to have multiple video player in a single html page

Tags: javascript, html, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api, video-player

I'm having a problem with the YouTube api:
I'm developing a website and I want to have a video to start when I open his relative image: I used this code for the first of them and it work:

```
              <script>
                // 2. This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
               // var tag = document.createElement('script');

               // tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
                //var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
                firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);


                 function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
                  player = new YT.Player('player', {
                    height: '360',
                    width: '640',
                    videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
                    events: {
                      'onReady': onPlayerReady,
                      'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
                    }
                  });
                }
              </script>
              <button class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">
                <i class="fa fa-times"></i>
                Chiudi</button>
            </div>
```

now, if i put the same code in another photo with another video on the same page it doesn't work adn gives me this error:"TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentNode' of undefined".
(if I click others photo it doesn't display the video even if I change the reference) (I'm pretty new to boostrap and js) 
if you can give me some hints I would appreciate, thanks and have a nice day
(sorry for my broken english)

Answer (score 0):

please try this code because of i am not understand your quotation you can used this code. i think this code useful.

As in the question you mention only to have two video tag with the same sources, here is a possibility. 
The idea is the following:

```
<--script-->

    var myvid = document.getElementById('myvideo');

    myvid.addEventListener('ended', function(e) {
      // get the active source and the next video source.
      // I set it so if there's no next, it loops to the first one
      var activesource = document.querySelector("#myvideo source.active");
      var nextsource = document.querySelector("#myvideo source.active + source") || document.querySelector("#myvideo source:first-child");

      // deactivate current source, and activate next one
      activesource.className = "";
      nextsource.className = "active";

      // update the video source and play
      myvid.src = nextsource.src;
      myvid.play();
    });


<!--html-->
    <video id="myvideo" width="320" height="240" controls style="background:black">
      <source class="active" src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
      <source src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    </video>
```